# (Windows) Find files that do NOT have a specific attribute

Tags: windows, cmd, command, dir

I know that I can use the following to get a list of all files that have the archive attribute: 'dir /b /a:a'

However, I cannot seem to get a list of files that do not have this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir /b /a:-a
```

inhelp `(dir /?)` it is stated (`- reverses`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not find this on the Microsoft website description of the dir command. Works perfectly.